# Tableview button click need pickerview in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

Creating the UIpickerview in tableview button click. When click the each button first time the picker want to show . if i click the same button in another time picker want to hide and get the picker value. here i put my code only the last cell index done the process the first cell index is not working? how can i fix this issues help me!!! here screen!.
create the picker in global like

UIPickerView *myPickerView;` and acess in tableview

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [_arr_tags count]; /// in tag array number of button count
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


         /// create a button

        UIImage *ButtonImagecmt = [UIImage imageNamed:@"orangeButton@2x.png"];
        UIButton *myButtoncmt = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        myButtoncmt.frame = CGRectMake(10,50,90,35);
        [myButtoncmt setBackgroundImage:ButtonImagecmt forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [myButtoncmt addTarget:self action:@selector(picker_select:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        [cell addSubview:myButtoncmt];

        flg=1; /// first time picker want to hide so flag set 1.




        myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 0, 160, 180)];
        myPickerView.delegate = self;
        myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
        myPickerView.hidden=true;
        [cell addSubview:myPickerView];

    }


    return cell;
}
- (IBAction)picker_select:(id)search
{
    if (flg==1)
    {
        /// first time button clickt picker want to display
        myPickerView.hidden=false;
        flg=0;
    }
    else
    {
        /// secound time button click picker want to hide 
        myPickerView.hidden=true;
        flg=1;
    }

}
```

This code only working in last cell. want to work in all the cell in table view

[image]

Comment: Instead of Checking the 'flg' use button selection status. I hope taht will be better. Here it is not working because you have only one 'flg' variable for all the cells.

Comment: how can i check the flg for each  button click in tableview cell. how can hide and show the pickerview in each cell button click in tableview help me.

Comment: In your IBAction try reloading the tableView, as, at the moment, you are setting the myPickerView.hidden but then I can't see that you are refreshing the tableView. Hope this helps.

Comment: i want to hide the picker in each cell button click. its working last cell if i click the first cell button the last cell picker hide and displaying.. each cell button click picker want to hide and display.. how can i achive tis help???

Comment: tabeview relaod is not working

Comment: your 'flg' concept will not work. If you want to go with that approach you have to keep n number of 'flg' variables depending on your number of cells. So as per me button selected status is a better option. If button is not selected show picker else hide it

Comment: And for every cells there will be separate button (either fresh instance or reused instance).

Comment: can give any sample code for me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me explain your error after that I will suggest you other way. 
You are declaring UIPickerView *myPickerView; in **out side** of following method

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But you are initializing myPickerView **inside** of following method

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and again you are trying to access myPickerView **outside** of the following method

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

simply the object myPickerView represents last cell pickerview. so what ever button you tapped in table view, myPickerView  always represents last cell pickerview. As per reusability concept, you can't see this picker until you are loading last cell  on screen. 
so what I am suggesting you to work with your code

set index row as  tag to your button like bellow in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
myButtoncmt.tag = indexpath.row;
```

now in the same way set tag to your pickerview also(I am not recommended this but I am trying to resolve issue with your code ) like bellow

```
myPickerView.tag = [_arr_tags count]+indexpath.row;
```

Now in - (IBAction)picker_select:(id)search access that using following code

```
UIButton *tempBtn =(UIButton *) search;
UITableViewCell *cell= [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:tempBtn.tag inSection:0]]
UIPickerView *pickerView = [cell viewWithTag:[_arr_tags count]+tempBtn.tag];
pickerView.hidden = !pickerView.isHidden;
```

Now you can see all pickers. try and let me know your result

Comment: if i click the first cell buton the picker want to display. again i click the same buton the picker want hide. this can be done by all the cell in tableview.

Comment: The same way want to create a label and set the tag value

Comment: Sorry, I havn't understand your question. Please describe your question

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath  want to create one label. if i click the button however the picker get hide and display. the sameway the label want to hide and display in the button click. in that label want to display the pickerview selected objects.